# Styling Data React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I am new to React and having some trouble here- I am trying to use Sass to style a component in React. For some reason it isn't working. I am getting an error that `'styles' is defined but never used` I'm not sure why this is happening as my other components are working fine. Probably something to do with the function around the jsx? I am getting an error `'styles' is defined but never used` Any help is greatly appreciated!

Covers.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { videos } from '../../data/videos.json';
import styles from './covers.module.sass';

export const Covers = () => (
  <div className="cover-container">
    {videos.map((data, key) => {
        return (
            <Cover 
              key={key}
              cover={data.cover}
              title={data.title}
              subtitle={data.subtitle}
              description={data.description}
            />
        );
      })}
  </div>
);

const Cover = ({title, subtitle, description, cover}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src={cover} className="cover-image" />
      <h1 className="cover-title">{title}</h1>
      <h2 className="cover-subtitle">{subtitle}</h2>
      <p className="cover-description">{description}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Covers;
```

covers.module.sass

```
.cover-container
  text-align: center
  color: white

.cover-image
  width: 200px
  height: 200px
  object-fit: cover

.cover-title 
  font-size: 7em

.cover-subtitle
  font-size: 4em

.cover-description
  font-size: 2em
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using CSS Modules but not using properly. CSS Modules allows you to scope locally your css, given an unique identifier to the classes for given scope. This avoids name collisions, a problem that can occur given the global scope nature in CSS.

but for that work properly at your file after importing the style as you do:

```
import styles from './covers.module.sass';
```

you need to use that `styles` object imported at your `className` declaration, rather than passing a string name like you do. Since you are not applying `styles` anywhere you get this error warning. You should pass to `className` style with the corresponding desired class.

therefore, the correct way to apply `styles` would be:

```
<div>
  <img src={cover} className={styles.cover-image} />
  <h1 className={styles.cover-title}>{title}</h1>
  <h2 className={styles.cover-subtitle}>{subtitle}</h2>
  <p className={styles.cover-description}>{description}</p>
</div>
```

as you do that your error is fixed, your styles work as expected, and at the browser you'll have unique classes generated which ensures that will not face any class name collision.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use className like this  `<img src={cover} className="cover-image" />`

correct would be `<img src={cover} className={styles.cover-image} />`

or

you can import sass file like this `import './covers.module.sass';` and use className like this `<img src={cover} className="cover-image" />`

ref: https://www.w3schools.com/react/react_sass.asp

Answer (score 1):

just replace the

`import styles from './covers.module.sass';`

with

`import './covers.module.sass';`